# Need to pass lead custom field value to partner when converting to lead to partner in OpenERP 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm new to OpenERP 7 and I'm trying to pass a custom field value from Lead to Partner when I convert a Lead to Partner.

I understand that I need to modify or add some functions in wizard directory of my new module (I assume I need to extend the crm module)

Is correct? Anyone can recommend me any example or let me know some tips?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not first learn openerp properly then ask question here

Comment: Seems logical and reasonably kind of your part, in fact it's what I'm doing right now.
But I need to learn all capabilities without going too deep, because I'm doing a report about openerp 7.0 capabilities.
I've made my first modules, and I following 2 books, but I don't have much time.
That's why I ask this kind of advanced topics despite my (yet) poor OpenERP level.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two methods defined in crm.`_lead_create_partner` and `_lead_create_contact`. These methods create partner and contact respectively. You can override these methods(first use the `_lead_create_partner`) to pass value to partner.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to start from there. Thanks for your tip!